# GetUserMedia alternative API

Tags: api, audio, camera, webrtc, getusermedia

GetUserMedia alternative API for capturing audio and video connections Peer to Peer because getUserMedia in Developing this, is there any alternative or could help me with browsers that support. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean? Another way to get audio and video stream that will work with WebRTC or just a way to get the streams period? Your wording is very confusing.

Comment: Yes, Another way to get audio and video, and create Peer to peer connections for video conferences, and I used getUserMedia (I used WebRTC, but it does not work very well). Also if you can give me solution that works in Mozilla, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer browsers using GetUserMedias would be perfect. A greeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not sure what your absolute goal is or how it would negate using WebRTC, here are some other options for you.

- [SilverLight](http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/).
- [flash-videoio](https://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/)
- Check out the [list of APIs](http://vsee.com/api) that VSee provides(VSee itself costs money, and so will most APIs outside of pure WebRTC/Flash).

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on WebRTC and was able to stream video easily. Following links helped me implement my requirements :
* http://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/
* Google Chrome extension : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search
* Chrome and Firefox extenion : https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment